# On hover overlay effect for Material UI CardMedia

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to create an overlay effect when moused over the CardMedia component of Material UI: this is what I have so far:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardMedia: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '100%',
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: 'pointer',
    },
  },
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
}));

const PhotoCard = ({ photo }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.cardMedia}
        image={photo.image}
        title="Paella dish"
      />
    </Card>
  );
};
```

What property can I add to cardMedia to have an on hover overlay effect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can try box-shadow

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: Hi @DeanJames I am trying to achieve something like Pinterest where if you hover over the card, there's a slight black overlay.